# Using multiple arguments to find and grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep, find

I am trying to make a script so that I can give command with variable number of arguments `myfind one two three` and it finds all files in the folder, then applies `grep -i one` then `grep -i two`, and `grep -i three` and so on.

I tried following code:

```
#! /bin/bash
FULLARG="find . | "
for arg in "$@"
do 
    FULLARG=$FULLARG" grep -i "$arg" | "
done
echo $FULLARG
$FULLARG
```

However, though the command is created but it is not working and giving following error:

```
$ ./myfind one  two three
find . | grep -i one | grep -i two | grep -i three |
find: unknown predicate `-i'
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the result of `find .` and keep filtering that out till you have command line arguments:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

result="$(find .)"
for arg in "$@"
do
    result=$(echo "$result" | grep -i "${arg}")
done

echo "$result"
```

Comment: Why do you use ${arg} and not $arg as you write $result?

Comment: `${arg}` and `$arg` mean the same thing; so, in this context, there's no real reason to prefer one or the other. You may need the `${}` when concatenating a string to a variable. E.g. `i="hello"; echo "$i_world"; echo "${i}_world"` will print an empty line (in fact `i_world` has not been defined) and "hello_world" (i.e. the value of `i` + "_world").

Comment: In that case it may be safer to always use `{}`, eg `"${result}"`

Comment: I agree. It can make the code quite harder to read, though.

Comment: Is `" "` around `${var}` needed everywhere?